# How to get config data from model in magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2, model, data

I have code file in model.How to get config data ?
I have error with AbstractMethod and getConfigData() in PHP storm .ERROR

> Class AbstractMethod is deprecated
>
> Method getConfigData is deprecated

```
class AdminPaymentMethod extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod{
/**
 * Payment code
 *
 * @var string|bool
 */
const CODE                  = 'adminpaymentmethod';
protected $_code            = self::CODE;
protected $_isOffline       = true;
protected $_canUseCheckout  = false;
protected $_canUseInternal  = true;

/**
 * Get pre select option from config
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function getDataPreSelect()
{
    return $this->getConfigData('preselect');
}}
```

file system.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <section id="payment">
        <group id="adminpaymentmethod" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label><![CDATA[Admin Payment Method]]></label>
            <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                <label><![CDATA[Enabled]]></label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                <comment><![CDATA[Version 1.0.0]]></comment>
            </field>
            <field id="title" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
                <label><![CDATA[Title]]></label>
            </field>
            <field id="sort_order" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label><![CDATA[Sort Orderr]]></label>
                <frontend_class>validate-number</frontend_class>
            </field>
            <field id="order_status" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                <label><![CDATA[New Order Status]]></label>
                <source_model>Magento\Sales\Model\Config\Source\Order\Status\NewStatus</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="allowspecific" translate="label" type="allowspecific" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                <label><![CDATA[Payment from Applicable Countries]]></label>
                <source_model>Magento\Payment\Model\Config\Source\Allspecificcountries</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="specificcountry" translate="label" type="multiselect" sortOrder="51" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                <label><![CDATA[Payment from Specific Countries]]></label>
                <source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>
                <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
            </field>
            <field id="preselect" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="55" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0" canRestore="1">
                <label><![CDATA[Pre Select]]></label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Can you post you full file? Also from where you want the config value, update the system.xml to your question as well?

Comment: i have updated my question.pls help me .

Answer (score 2):

**Update** :
This issue is already [reported](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5304) 
**\Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod** class is deprecated and You must not extend AbstractMethod class in your own payment method but just implement **Magento\Payment\Model\MethodInterface** interface.

You can also check [Magento Devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/payments-integrations/bk-payments-integrations.html) that how to implement payment methods with new updates and also magento team has provided a [sample payment module](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway) to use as sample

Comment: I know this code. I have error Class AbstractMethod is deprecated

Method getConfigData is deprecated

Comment: Im making a payment method offline.

Comment: Can I replace \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod with something ?

Comment: @ThànhTrungTô, you have to change and implement interface as detailed in devdocs.  However if you still want to use that class, then you should not define any method there in and only can define / override variables. ( i.e /**
     protected $_code = 'adminpaymentmethod';
    protected $_isOffline = false; )

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code:

```
class AdminPaymentMethod extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod{
    /**
     * Payment code
     *
     * @var string|bool
     */
    const CODE                  = 'adminpaymentmethod';
    protected $_code            = self::CODE;
    protected $_isOffline       = true;
    protected $_canUseCheckout  = false;
    protected $_canUseInternal  = true;
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    ){
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Get pre select option from config
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getDataPreSelect()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('payment/adminpaymentmethod/preselect');
    }
}
```

Comment: it will run.but i have error Class AbstractMethod is deprecated and Missing parent constructor call (php storm) (standard code) ~~!

Comment: Can you check link: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5304

Comment: I think you are using old code. You need to follow this link for payment method creation:https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/payments-integrations/payment-gateway/payment-gateway-intro.html

Comment: I have read through this document but I do not understand it well. I have an exercise that is taking a model to get data from config data.

Comment: Can you post your whole payment module files?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U36jbm-FvSIaTRXylOSzEO3YlUuF5lRw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is the magento version you are using?

Comment: version is 2.2.5

Comment: Where are getting this error?

Comment: Class AbstractMethod is deprecated and Method getDataConfig() is deprecated when i use php storm (standard code sniffer)

Comment: Ok. But its working fine with Magento 2.2.4

Comment: i think run on local will fine but if run  on sever  will error

Comment: Can I replace \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod with something ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function for getting configuration values in your custom module's model.

Just Use `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig`,
In your constructor argument and set the class property: `$this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;`

```
$config_path = 'payment/adminpaymentmethod/preselect';
public function getDataPreSelect($config_path)
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        $config_path,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );
}
```

Comment: Can I replace \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod with something ?